# Why do we need IEEE 754 remainder?

Tags: floating-point, modulo, ieee-754

I just read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158120/math-ieeeremainder-returns-negative-results-why) (especially the last comments).

Then I was wondering, why we actually need this was of giving the remainder. But it seems, that not many people "on google" were interested in that before...

Comment: @MarkDickinson what does that mean? Can you add that as a complete answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for reasons why you would want it, one is for what is known as "range reduction"

Let's say you want `sind` function for computing the sine of an argument in degrees. A naive way to do this would be

```
sind(x) = sin(x*pi/180)
```

However `pi` here is not the true irrational number `pi`, but instead the floating point number closest to `pi`. This leads to things like `sind(180) == 1.2246467991473532e-16`, and SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646477/why-is-sin180-not-zero-when-using-python-and-numpy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961900/java-strange-behavior-with-sin-and-toradians) (and many, many more).

But sine is a periodic function, so if we compute

```
remainder(x,90.0)
```

we get a value on the interval [-45,45]. Note that 0, 90, 180, 270, etc. become exactly 0, and multiplying by `pi/180` is still 0. Therefore taking the appropriately signed `sin` or `cos`, we can get the exact result at these values (and if you do some basic error analysis, you can demonstrate that it also reduces the error at other values).

Two follow up points:

1. How do you determine which `sin` or `cos` to use? Well, that's what [`remquo`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/remquo/) is for.
2. Unfortunately, this still won't give `sind(30.0) == 0.5` exactly, due to the vagaries of intermediate rounding. There are ways to fix this, e.g. see what the [Julia library does](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/7b54558876e5b38188d0b0bf14f672c9746ff39f/base/special/trig.jl).

Comment: So to sum it up roughly: It's used in mathmatics for getting more correct results on irrational numbers, right?

Thanks for the explanation. I figured I'm not deep enough into this to understand it completely. Still some things to learn.

Comment: It's a great example, which made it click for me - any periodic "float" quantity (like angles). I know dozens of applications of modulus (mostly on integers though), but despite seeing the symmetry in remainder I really couldn't guess what this powerful technology was for. So thanks for the question and answer.

Comment: So a remainder of N produces a range of (-N/2, N/2)?

Comment: @AaronFranke Yes, but the interval is closed [-N/2, N/2].