# Replicate C# Math.IEEERemainder in Lua?

Tags: c#, lua, modulo

I am trying to replicate the behavior of Math.IEEERemainder (in C#) in Lua. I know that I can always write the entire thing from scratch, but I am trying to avoid it if there is something built-in.

I have tried the % operator and math.fmod. None of them behave the same.

For instance:

```
Math.IEEERemainder(3.0,2.0) //-1
(3.0%2.0) --1
math.fmod(3.0,2.0) --1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function IEEERemainder(x, y)
   y = y + 0.0
   local q1 = math.floor(x/y)
   local q2 = math.ceil(x/y)
   local r1 = x - y * q1
   local r2 = x - y * q2
   local d1 = math.abs(r1)
   local d2 = math.abs(r2)
   local r = (d1 < d2 or d1 == d2 and q1 % 2 == 0) and r1 or r2
   return r == 0 and x < 0 and -r or r
end
```

Comment: Got it, so I guess LUA does not have one built-in, thanks a lot!

Comment: @nxgtrturbo - Where this function might be useful?  I have no idea  :-)

Comment: For very specific cases, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671975/why-do-we-need-ieee-754-remainder/27378075#27378075

Comment: @nxgtrturbo - Thanks.  Indeed, sin(x) would be better calculated using `IEEERemainder(x, 2*pi)` than `fmod(x, 2*pi)`