# How to create an array of multiples of Pi to use the Cosine function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an array of numbers from -Pi to +Pi with a step size of Pi/4. However, using `linspace` does not give me the accuracy I want, I am guessing it's a problem with the data type.

```py
arr = np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,math.pi/4)
print(math.cos(arr[2]))
```

This does not output zero but outputs an extremely small number. How do I fix the data type so that I get the output as zero?

Comment: That code raises `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter into `np.linspace` is the number of samples, not the size of them. In your case, you want 9 samples.

```
arr = np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,9)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[-3.14159265 -2.35619449 -1.57079633 -0.78539816  0.          0.78539816
  1.57079633  2.35619449  3.14159265]
```

To explain why you are not getting exactly zero at `-pi/2`, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647014/3923163).

> The number π cannot be represented exactly as a floating-point number.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the numpy arange function:

```
import math
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(-math.pi,math.pi,math.pi/4) #replace pi with 5/4*pi to include pi as endpoint
print(math.cos(arr[2]))
```

Comment: Note that `arange` **excludes** the end `math.pi`, while `linspace` **includes** it, unless specified otherwise. Of course `linspace` expects number of samples, not step size, as mentioned.